# How to give background colour for alert OK action button and how to give top space for title in alert in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uicolor

I have created alert with image view i need that image to rounded and i need to give background colour to alert done button. please help me in the code.

here is my alert code:

```
 func showAlert(){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title:"      Profile created    \n     Sccessfully     ", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let doneAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "DONE", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    })
    alertController.addAction(doneAlert)

    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.height/2
    image.layer.borderWidth = 1
    alertController.view.addSubview(image)

    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    alertController.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: alertController.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    alertController.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: alertController.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: -20))

    alertController.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40))
    alertController.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: image, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 40))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I need alert like this

[Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcuuO.png)

Comment: From the documentation for `UIAlertController`: *"The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."*. Create your own custom alert class or find a 3rd party alert class that supports whatever customizations you need.

Comment: Create your own UIView with button and lable inside it.

Comment: @BhawinRanpura okay, i tried that one also, if we create view with button then how can we disable userinteraction to bagckground tableview. that is my problem, is there any solution

Comment: You can place everything in full screen view and present that view on window to make it generic.

Comment: Create Main View set its background color to Black, and set its alpha to 0.5. Inside main view create your view with label and button. and per requirement HIDE n SHOW main view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **Important**
>
> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

You're probably better off using an existing library that implements this, such as e.g. https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift, or implementing your own alert from scratch.

Comment: I have an example of a presented view controller that behaves like an alert here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method. It tweaks the UIAlertController

```
func showConfiguredUIAlertControllerWithTitle(_ title:String, message:String, messageTextAlignment:NSTextAlignment, actionButtonTitle:String, actionViewBackgroundColor color:UIColor, alertTint:UIColor){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        //configuring the alert view sans action
        let alertMainSubviews = alert.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews
        let upperView = (alertMainSubviews?.first)! as UIView
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = messageTextAlignment
        let attributedStringTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange])
        let attributedStringMessage = NSAttributedString(string: "\n" + message, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
        alert.setValue(attributedStringTitle, forKey: "attributedTitle")
        alert.setValue(attributedStringMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")

        let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 45, width: alert.view.frame.size.width, height: 1.0))
        line.backgroundColor = .black
        upperView.addSubview(line)
        upperView.bringSubviewToFront(line)

        //configuring the action view
        let actionView = (alertMainSubviews?[1])! as UIView
        actionView.backgroundColor = color
        alert.view.tintColor = alertTint

        //adding action to alert
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: actionButtonTitle, style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Call this as following:

```
showConfiguredUIAlertControllerWithTitle("Hey There!", message: "I am your friendly neighbourhood Spiderman", messageTextAlignment: .left, actionButtonTitle: "OK", actionViewBackgroundColor: .orange, alertTint: .white)
```

Comment: While this might work, it's a bad idea because Apple specifically states that you shouldn't do this. A future update to iOS could cause such code to fail, or worse, crash.

Comment: I concur with that. I am just showing that there's a way to do what he's asked.

Comment: its working but i need to add image view in top, is there any chance to add image

Comment: the way I have added a line, you can add an imageView  there, with appropriate frame size of course!